# How to measure the moving angle of a vector

Tags: python, pandas

The following produces the angle of vector that is fixed to the first given coordinate. I want to apply a moving window that calculates the angle based on the previous coordinate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],                           
        'X' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,2,2,4,4],
        'Y' : [0,0,1,1,2,2,-1,-1,-3,-3],
    })

x = df['X'] - df['Time'].map(df.groupby('Time')['X'].max().shift()).fillna(df['X']) 
y = df['Y'] - df['Time'].map(df.groupby('Time')['Y'].max().shift()).fillna(df['Y']) 

df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(x, y)
df['Angle'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])
```

Out:

```
   Time  X  Y  Rotation  Angle
0     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
1     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
2     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
3     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
4     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
5     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
6     4  2 -1  2.356194  135.0
7     4  2 -1  2.356194  135.0
8     5  4 -3  2.356194  135.0
9     5  4 -3  2.356194  135.0
```

Intended Output:

```
   Time  X  Y  Rotation  Angle
0     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
1     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
2     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
3     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
4     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
5     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
6     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
7     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
8     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
9     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
```

So the angle should reference the previous coordinate.

The first point moves in the same direction so 0 degrees is ideal. It then deviates on a 45 degree angle from time pint 2-3, which is good. At this point I'm hoping to use this direction as a reference, so the direction it's currently on it 0. Hence the subsequent time point would signify a 180 degree move. This would also generate 0 degrees on the final point as its moving in the same direction.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Your arguments to atan look flipped

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I've included a figure displaying the issue. The current output is referenced from the first coordinate. rather than a moving reference.

Comment: @AMC, is this still unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) 
to consider only a single angular value per row. Then We can use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to take the angular coordinate of the previous moment. 
Since this must be subtracted from the original values ​​of the Angle column, we can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to align the indexes and to perform the subtraction

```
new_df = df.assign(Angle = df['Angle'].sub(df['Time'].map(df.drop_duplicates('Time')
                                                            .set_index('Time')['Angle']
                                                            .shift(fill_value = 0)))
                  )
print(new_df)
   Time  X  Y  Rotation  Angle
0     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
1     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
2     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
3     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
4     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
5     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
6     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
7     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
8     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
9     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
```

---

Alternative with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
new_df = df.assign(Angle = df['Angle'].sub(df.drop_duplicates('Time')['Angle']
                                             .shift(fill_value = 0))
                                      .ffill()


            )
print(new_df)
   Time  X  Y  Rotation  Angle
0     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
1     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
2     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
3     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
4     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
5     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
6     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
7     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
8     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
9     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
```

---

In your question the dataframe is ordered by `Time`, if it were not then you would need:

```
new_df = df.assign(Angle = df['Angle'].sub(df['Time'].map(df.drop_duplicates('Time')
                                                            .set_index('Time')
                                                            .sort_index()['Angle']
                                                            .shift(fill_value = 0)))
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like Jonboy's question. They are interesting and challenging :). I also come up with solution using groupby `first`, `diff` and merge back

```
df1 = np.degrees(df.groupby(['X','Y'], sort=False).Rotation.first().diff()
                   .fillna(0)).rename('Angle')

df_final = df.merge(df1, left_on=['X','Y'], right_index=True)

Out[71]:
   Time  X  Y  Rotation  Angle
0     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
1     1  0  0  0.000000    0.0
2     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
3     2  0  1  0.000000    0.0
4     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
5     3 -1  2 -0.785398  -45.0
6     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
7     4  2 -1  2.356194  180.0
8     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
9     5  4 -3  2.356194    0.0
```